# I am not able to run my flutter app it throws IOClient exception

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

**When I run my app, it gives this error:**

**Compiler message:**

---

```
/C:/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.1/lib/src/io_client.dart:31:31: Error: Expected ')' before this.
      var ioRequest = (sawait _inner.openUrl(request.method, request.url))

                          
/C:/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.1/lib/src/io_client.dart:31:24: Error: The getter 'sawait' isn't defined for the class 'IOClient'.

'IOClient' is from 'package:http/src/io_client.dart' ('/C:/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.1/lib/src/io_client.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'sawait'.
      var ioRequest = (sawait _inner.openUrl(request.method, request.url))
                   ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

it clearly says that the line,

```
var ioRequest = (sawait _inner.openUrl(request.method, request.url))
```

should be corretly written as follows,

```
var ioRequest = await _inner.openUrl(request.method, request.url)
```

there is a typo `sawait` should be `await`.

please run the following command as the issue is inside .pub-cache/

```
dart pub cache repair
```

Also, do `flutter clean` afterwards and then try to run the app.